# What should I do if my dismiss does not work after a QRcode scan?

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, avcapturesession

I am going to scan the `QR code` in the `webView`.

`QR code` scans well and data can be read,

but the problem is, the camera screen won't close after scanning. I'm running a `dismiss()` function.

**webView Load**

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var wkWebView: WKWebView!
...
 let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        contentController.add(self, name: "native")

        config.userContentController = contentController

        wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: wkWebView.frame, configuration: config)

        wkWebView.uiDelegate = self
        wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self

        view.addSubview(wkWebView)
        view.addSubview(indicator)
let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: webUrl, withExtension: "html")
let myRequest = URLRequest(url: localFilePath)
wkWebView.load(myRequest)
```

**QRCode Scan**

```swift
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    func qrcodeScan(){
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func found(code: String) {
        Log.Info(code)
    }


    func failed() {
        captureSession = nil
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }


    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
```

As you can see from my code, I'm trying to get the camera window down after reading the `QR code`.

But the camera screen is still on the frozen screen. No matter how long I wait, I can't see the web view screen. What's the problem?

Comment: Are you showing the webview and the QR code scanning in a different `UIViewController` ?

Comment: No,  @MarwenDoukh-MaruänDuch I only showed the code of the same file by dividing it up to enhance the readability of the code.

Comment: try this: `previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()` instead of `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: I'll make it as an answer , so other developers could use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `previewLayer` is taking all the screen (bounds) and it is hiding the webview, so you should remove the `previewLayer` from the super layer in order to show the webview.

So the solution is to use this :

`previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()`

instead of

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`